# Oracle MAF : Connection timed out error for BLOB data

Tags: java, oracle, base64, blob, oracle-maf

I have simple table in `Oracle DB` with `ID` as Integer (`PK`) and `ATTACHMENT` as **BLOB** column where I can store `image, audio, video, File..etc`.

I have created Web service for that table and when I consume through `URL` it gives like this.

```
<List>
   <attachment>
     <attachment>oracle.sql.BLOB@27c59ba1</attachment>
     <id>101</id>
   </attachment>
</List>
```

When I consume using, oracle mobile application it is always giving `Connection timed out` error. Below is the error log for your reference,

```
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - GenericInvokeRequestHandler - process] Process AdfException caught: ERROR [oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfException] - Unable to load class: Didn't find class "oracle.omss.containerization.OMSSContainerizationNativeLayerImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.ATTACHMENT-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.company.ATTACHMENT-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
Unable to load sqlite_jni fromSQLite.library.path=/data/data/com.company.ATTACHMENT/storage/jvm/lib, trying system default: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /data/data/com.company.ATTACHMENT/storage/jvm/lib/libsqlite_jni.so
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.application - DBPersistenceManager - oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.v2.persistence.manager.DBPersistenceManager] Processing SQL script META-INF/ATTACHMENT.sql, executing statement CREATE TABLE ATTACHMENT (      ATTACHMENT VARCHAR ,      ID NUMERIC  NOT NULL,    CONSTRAINT ATTACHMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY(ID));
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.application - DBPersistenceManager - oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.v2.persistence.manager.DBPersistenceManager] Processing SQL script META-INF/ATTACHMENT.sql, executing statement CREATE TABLE DATA_SYNCH_ACTIONS (      ID NUMERIC NOT NULL,      SERVICE_CLASS_NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,      ENTITY_CLASS_NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,      JSON_PAYLOAD VARCHAR ,      ACTION VARCHAR NOT NULL,      DATE_CREATED DATE NOT NULL,      DATE_LAST_SYNCH DATE NOT NULL,      LAST_SYNCH_ERROR VARCHAR,      CUSTOM_METHOD_NAME VARCHAR,    CONSTRAINT DSA_PK PRIMARY KEY(SERVICE_CLASS_NAME ,ID));
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.application - DBPersistenceManager - oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.v2.persistence.manager.DBPersistenceManager] Processing SQL script META-INF/ATTACHMENT.sql, executing statement CREATE TABLE WEB_SERVICE_CALL (      ID NUMERIC  NOT NULL,      CONNECTION VARCHAR ,      REQUEST VARCHAR ,      METHOD VARCHAR ,      REQUEST_HEADERS VARCHAR ,      DURATION NUMERIC ,      REQUEST_PAYLOAD VARCHAR ,      RESPONSE_PAYLOAD VARCHAR ,      ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR ,      TIMESTAMP DATE ,    CONSTRAINT WEB_SERVICE_CALL_PK PRIMARY KEY(ID));
Back Channel Hidden Feature: Received Event: deviceready
Back Channel Hidden Feature - Startup is complete.
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - Utility - printCurrentStackTrace] Cannot serialize the object as cyclical reference to oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.util.MCSManager (object getter method - instance) was detected during the JSON serialization process. A possible resolution to this could be to make the oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.util.MCSManager field transient.
java.lang.Throwable: Cannot serialize the object as cyclical reference to oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.util.MCSManager (object getter method - instance) was detected during the JSON serialization process. A possible resolution to this could be to make the oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.util.MCSManager field transient.
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.api.JSONBeanSerializationHelper.toJSONActual(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.api.JSONBeanSerializationHelper.toJSONActual(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.api.JSONBeanSerializationHelper.toJSONActual(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.api.JSONBeanSerializationHelper.toJSON(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.event.DataChangeEvent.toJSON(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.api.JSONBeanSerializationHelper.toJSONActual(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.api.JSONBeanSerializationHelper.toJSON(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.event.DataChangeManager.getDataChangeEventJSON(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.event.DataChangeManager.createDataChangeEvent(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.request.EmbeddedToNativeRequest.flushDataChangeEvents(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.event.DataChangeManager.flushDataChangeEvents(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.api.AdfmfJavaUtilities.flushDataChangeEvent(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfmf.framework.EmbeddedFeatureContext$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



DalvikProxySelector.getProxyForURL(): No proxy found
FetchCallback AttachmentService Method Called.!
End of ViaInspFileAttachments FetchCallback
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - RestTransportLayer - readResponse] Exception while reading response: java.io.IOException: Connection timed out
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.application - RestPersistenceManager - oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.v2.persistence.manager.RestPersistenceManager] Error invoking REST GET service /query/Attachment.findAll : Connection timed out
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.application - AbstractRemotePersistenceManager - oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.v2.persistence.manager.AbstractRemotePersistenceManager] Error invoking REST GET service /query/Attachment.findAll : Connection timed out
DalvikProxySelector.getProxyForURL(): No proxy found
Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.util.TaskExecutor.lambda$updateStatus$14(TaskExecutor.java:115)
    at oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.util.TaskExecutor$$Lambda$2/9021663.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.util.TaskExecutor.lambda$updateStatus$14(TaskExecutor.java:115)
    at oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.util.TaskExecutor$$Lambda$2/9021663.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - RestServiceAdapterImpl - getOutputStream] ERROR: Retrieving OutputStream failed - java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - RestTransportLayer - sendPayload] Exception while writing payload. Connection:oracle.microedition.io.HttpConnectionImpl@e8e832
DalvikProxySelector.getProxyForURL(): No proxy found
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - RestServiceAdapterImpl - getOutputStream] ERROR: Retrieving OutputStream failed - java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - RestTransportLayer - sendPayload] Exception while writing payload. Connection:oracle.microedition.io.HttpConnectionImpl@603e43
DalvikProxySelector.getProxyForURL(): No proxy found
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - RestServiceAdapterImpl - getOutputStream] ERROR: Retrieving OutputStream failed - java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - RestTransportLayer - sendPayload] Exception while writing payload. Connection:oracle.microedition.io.HttpConnectionImpl@463673
DalvikProxySelector.getProxyForURL(): No proxy found
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - GenericInvokeRequestHandler - process] Process AdfException caught: ERROR [oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfException] - Unable to load class: Didn't find class "oracle.omss.containerization.OMSSContainerizationNativeLayerImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.ATTACHMENT-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.company.ATTACHMENT-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
FetchCallback AttachmentService Method Called.!
End of ViaInspFileAttachments FetchCallback
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - RestServiceAdapterImpl - getOutputStream] ERROR: Retrieving OutputStream failed - java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - RestTransportLayer - sendPayload] Exception while writing payload. Connection:oracle.microedition.io.HttpConnectionImpl@f1c53a
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.application - RestPersistenceManager - oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.v2.persistence.manager.RestPersistenceManager] Error invoking REST POST service /entity/Attachment : Connection timed out
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.application - AbstractRemotePersistenceManager - oracle.ateam.sample.mobile.v2.persistence.manager.AbstractRemotePersistenceManager] Error invoking REST POST service /entity/Attachment : Connection timed out
```

The thing is, I'm trying to store the `base64` image into DB. But without success, below is the `sample base64 image string`

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABQODxIPDRQSEBIXFRQYHjIhHhwcHj0sLiQySUBMS0dARkVQWnNiUFVtVkVGZIhlbXd7gYKBTmCNl4x9lnN+gXz/2wBDARUXFx4aHjshITt8U0ZTfHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHz/wAARCAJJA+gDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwC9RS0V1nCJRS4ooAKKKKACilooASilooATFFLRQAlFLiigBKKWigBKKWigApMUtHegAooooAKSlooAKKKKACijFGKACiijFABRiiloASiiigQUUfSloASilooASilxSd6ACjFLRQAlFLRQAlFLRTASilooASilxRQAlGKWigBKKWigBKKWigBMUUtFACUUtFACUUtGKAEpKWigQmKXFFFACUUuKWgBuKKWigApKWigBMUUtFACUYpaKBiYopaKBCUUtFACUUtFACUUtJQAmKKWigBKKXFFACYopaKAEopaKAEoNLRQAlFLijFACY9qMUtFACUUUtADaKdSUAJRilooASjFKaKAEopaKAExRS0UAJRS0YoATtRilxRQAlFLikxQAlFLRQAlFLRQAlGKWjFACUUtJQAlFLiigRJiilxRUliUUuKKAEopaKAEopaKACiiigBKWiigAoxRRQAYooooAKKWigBKMUtFACCjFLRQAlFLRTASilooATFFLSUAFGKWjFACUUtFACUYpaKAEopaKAEopaMUCEopaKAEopaKACkpaKAEopaMUAGKKKKBiUUtGKBCUuKKKAEoxS0UAJRS0UAJS0UUAJRS4ooASilxRQAlFLRQAmKKXFFACYopaKAEopaKAEopaMUAJRS0UAJRilooASilooASilpKACkp1JQAlFLRQAlFLRigBKKWigBKKWigQlFLSUAFFFFMAopaSkAUlLRTASjFLRSASilooASilooASilpKYBRS0UgEopaKYCUmKWigApKWikAlFLRTGJRS0UCEopaMUAJSUtH1oASilxRigBKKWigB9LRRUliUtFFABRRRQAUUVXmvYIXCu3PpSvYCxRVSDUI5bl4CVyOVIP3hVvj2oTT2C1goxS0UwEopaKAEopaKAEopaKAExRS0UCExRS0UAJS0UUAJiloooAKKKKACiiigBKWiigAooooAKMUUUAFFLikoAKKKMUAFFLSYpgFFLSUAFGKKWgBKKKWgBKKWigBMUUuKKAEopaKBCUUtJigAopaKAEopaSgAopaTFABRS0UAJSYp1JQAYopaKAExRS4pKAEpaWkoAKKWkoAKSlooAKTFLRQAlFLRQAlFLRQAlFLikxQAUUUUAFJS0UAJRS0UAJRS0UAJRS0UAJRS0UAJRS0YoASilooASilxSUAFFFFABikpaKAEopaKAEooz7Uhb0oAWigE0tACUUtFACfWilpKACiiigApKWigBKKWkoEFFFFAwooooESUUtFSaCUUtJQIKOlLUVwpaFgAT7DvQApljGRvHHvXK6jKXuWBbcAflJGK03s5o1Z5wgz/CG5ArHnjwT147HsKxqO6sawWpAkjLMpDFSGAyK6bT5zJKyZJIOK5Z+vBya6bRYkgg82bCOerMcUqRVS1jWoqo2oQgttJYA4yBwangnSdcowNb3MSSloxRQIMUUUYoAKKKKAACkpaKYBRS0UAJRiilHSgBMUySRYlDOcKTjNZ2p6kYHMSNtYdcjrWR/aMiCWMcxydQ1ZyqJFxg2dX1xRiqn2hraytnZCymMbj3FW1IZQw6EVadyWrBRS0UxCYopaKBCUUtFACUUtFACYopaKAEopaKAEopcUmKBhSZp2KMUAJRS4ooASilooEJRS0UAJRS0UAFFFGKACkpcUUAJS0UUAJiilooASloxRQAlFLRQAlFLRQAlFLRQAlFLRQAlFLRQAlFLRQAlFLRQAlFLSUAFFFFAgopaSgYlFLRQAlFLRQITFFLRQMSiiloASiiigQYooxRQAUUUUAFJS0UAJRS0UAJRS4ooASilooASilpKACilpKAExRilooGJijFLRQISjFLRigYlFLRQISjFLikoAKKKKAEopaMUAJRilooASilxRQA+iilpFiUYpsjrGMscCs651hY2xGobHvUuSW4JXLtzcfZxlhketZ8etRmbYxAVj8p9Pao7nU4bu2K4ZG6q3YGsCT74x0PpWc59i4wvubt4VmJmaby484LdSfYCst1ZnBOCD0J9KWxtzcpINx3RfMQeeKF2tJLGh4Uce9YybZso2K0iKr4GMg9fetZpVv5U/0WSSWFQWVXwp98Vi5MknpkgVo31tJp86OshVivJB7VUboGro0rO6s54hD80D5OA49Txg1PbWlzBeuxI2dDgcMP8AGqtui6taSnAjdUC56DI54/StGxvVk0+KWdgrgbHz6jvWylcxcbFyimh0MfmK6lP7wPFQXc2bKSS2bzCOPk5Iq+ZE8rJJLmGIZkkVe3Wq51O33hd3Xoc8VyFw028+aWPPehJNnUZU8j61k6nYtUztrW5iuoy8RztOD7VNWH4efFxPGv3XQPj3FbtaRd0RJWYlFLijFUISjFLRQISqst4I5CvllwvUg9Kt1nakwngaG3geZmPJVePzqZPQpIjnv9OuY5YpGCORg71zn6GuclXYpXqOxPf6VLPYtGCdrYH3iex9KHtXijAkPBXcBntXNOV9zeMbGjZXj3SW9ojMyZBlb0x0FdERzxWFBMLTRYLiySFXJ2uz8gHPU0+L+3J3Zluo/LAyGUAqa3jojKSuzZoqvaTTOzRXSgTIobcBgNVmtCLBRTlUseKkSEk57UrpDUWyEA9hSkEdquLGO9RSqMcGp5iuQr0VIsRJ56UrQkfSq5kTysipKdjB5pKZNgoopaAEoopaAEoopaAEoopaAEopaSgAopaSgAopaKAEopaKAEopaSgAopaSgAxRS0lMAopaSkAUUUUwCiiigQUUUUAFJS0UAFFFFABSYpRRQAlFLRQAlFLRigBKKWjFACUgOadjNMHBoAdSU6koAKSlooASilooASilooASilpKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigApKWigBKKWigBKKWigBKKKKACiijI9aACiiigAoopMigBaKQsBSB1NAC0UhPPHSlBzQAUUtJQAUUhcCmh6AsOozTSc04e9K40g696KCMciii4OLJKa7BBkkfnSSyLEpLsABXLarqU1xIUiP7sVLlYpJt2RLqepzSTlYHCoP1rKklLgh/vZznvQoDJk8YqNhxwc1zt3ZvGKRbWVfsQAJ81m59MVBu/d4PrxUUbbT60/kIT79KloqxMtw8EzGJyARjio9xjcOG5PWo2BFIzE4FOwySEgOM5+8D+tbGuXCTxhMfvEwMeo9azrQxRwTSygOwGFHv61ahtZFRZnkRy+DuJ5xVImRPo1pcSxTIhEasQCWHJ+lJf6XPaktvPlH0OQPwpBqF7BuMTgZPA2jFIusXbDZewrJCw6EbT+FN2sLfUoQTywOQHIWTg4PBrSFjcafELu3uMFu6cg/UVjzhFl3QktGTkZ6itOOSRPIUuDG3DKT1FShsZe3MV/Fu2LDOv3gBw3uKoG3fy+x9Ks3QT7Q5jXYM8VA+4ZIJHHT1qZN3BbGh4cb/TlGDuCnGK6oc1zHhlM6i5DfdjJIq1favLDN+4HQ4IPQ1vF2RnPV2NK+1BLNCcb2HbNZcfiX94BLCAmeSD0rOv70Xcwk8oRtjBwetUHPJJFRKbvoEYdzv43WWNXjIKsMilxiubtb42tuII5ckxht3oxHT8K2NO1BL2BWbCSYwwz1NaxmmQ42LhAIOayrvUJfLkiiBiA4BHWtbFZ8ls15MSp8uDoT3elUTa0HDcw9txNGVUuVH3yTxmq0khMBhRsqOef1rd1Qw2dqtrDkZyT/wDXrCVRFHIZFIDIQue59awcbaG0XfUsSXWLOWzRIxGjKwXuw7irVvaM0KXelyNb5+8N2QMdjWKC2/nBJXBrQ0W9FpNIszkW7Llk/vGrUtSXE6exn+12izSJskztYe9WlUHtVe3RUiBR94c7tw75qwrcVYiVRUinHWoQ1O3UhjnkHQUgAqM0b8UAS5AppbPSoS9N8ynYVx7YqM+1IXpu454q0Qx9FMD84NPqiAPHU4FIWULuLrjIGc96y9Wvl8toImXceGycVzguZYpY2wdqOCVz1waylU5XYqMLnbsQjAMQpPY0tZkdtG+rwzCQskkRk2Fs4b0+lamCTWidyWhKKakqSFghyVODT6YhKKWigBKKWigBKKWigBKKWigBKMcUtFACUUtFACUUtFACUYpaMUAJRS0UAJRS4ooASiloxQAlFLRQAlGKWigBKKWigBKKKWgBKKKKAEopaMUAJSYp1FACUUuKMUAJSU6koASilooASiloxQISilooATrRilooASiiigBKKXFFABRRRQAlFLRigBKKXFGKAEppbngU+jFADRk9aWlpKAEPTpTQpp9FAxuDSgUtFACHpUZU54qWigCAqc0BGqbFGKAuR7Cep4p4GKWigAooooAaVB5prYHankUhAoAiz6U8NTti0bAKBpibqKNoopWHzHMX2rvd4AjCxemeTVCRkJJQlfarF3pd1YRl7lMDOKonp8wrnd+p0RS6D9p7kH6U0r6dKVemc/hSqQSQxx6HtUlDF64qQn5Nq8+ppGiYAHI5oU4BA6+tABFC0qttUkCmAAMQ3apELLxkgHnilkcSHdtAPfFAEbx90yRjn2qe1kYuI2YZOACT92ojkcg/KeMVGQB2pphY072CSL5WuUYDuOe9SHW/OGy8t45gOAwG0isuOMvzvC9+TVm0jSWYRsuSTw3rT6k201CVYm3NGcDriosMmMrnip71BBclAgAQY61IZHvLUAKqBeOByai1nqO+mhVAduMcd6R1LAEckUhjkjPBINH3xwcSDr70hl+yu1tLVjGMTvwSO1QTXRl5lZhjpUaxCVBulCOB82eOB/WmbVyBuz6bqq7JsrjS5JPcHvTT8496M4J5pnOevNBQ9GOfpU9tOYJVlxyGBNV06/NwDzmnbhsIA96GI6gamUuVWaRVibkZ7itKC7huP9U3HbPeuGLOxBbLdhntV+z+1tE08DfLCRuJrSM7GbgdLe2izDkZZjx7VgzpcP5iLDmCIEbmH61v2F6t5FzxIo+YUmqzLBpswZtpdCFHrVNJq6JTa0OXnurZjFLDCVKEFlPRqgXm4BZcRE5HsKmzbsAArBjgbmPFSwWPmyTq8oVNmYznhj6VitWbdDZ0K68yHyDEybcsrHowrWyawdA1OLBtLmQrLuwhYcfSty4lS3QvKcAVvHYxk7MczFVLMwAHc1Qn1VI87PnCjJxWfqmovcoEt+I+5PFYsryJIM4yRzg8GplLsEU2dbp+opfghOHHY96uEH1riLW7e0nWVOgbO0dxXX212l5F50IYKTjDdRThK6CSaJ8UuKbznmlya0IFwKMD0pDmlBoAMD0rE17UZLUrDEcEjt1rczzXPa7BJNd5YpGir1J5qJuyHFXepiCSTcZGfcccg02QjPB681NIimMiMh9p+8BTERdgLsrAHoOtc+50Gv4bVp7zzmk/1CbBnpiteO4Go+clu7JCnymVernuBXNI8sdqkccyJbS53Hvx61v6bfabBax28V0gIGTkY5reDurGU11NGKNYo1jX7qj86dTEkWRd0bB1PRgcil3GtDOw6imhjTlPY9aAsFNlljh/1jqv1NNuJltoWlfotcfqF7JdzeYw2jPAqJT5Rxjc7RWV03IwZfUGiuV0PUPs1+iSsfJk+Uj37GuvaJeaUZ3Q3CxFRQM9KcUIGa0uTZjaKXFGKBCUUtFACUUtJ060AFFJmlyaLjsFFHPekJ546UXCwtLQvNO2ehpXDlYyihhg4zQD2p3C1haKKKBBRRRQAUUmfalHPSgLBSU
```

Please share your idea, to resolve this issue if you have any?